# .NET: ForEach() extension methods and Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, foreach

I have a quick question: I do alot of iteration of Dictionary.Value collections and in annoys me that I have to call .ToList() to then be able to call .ForEach(), as it seems none of the enumerable collections in a Dictionary (The Dictionary itself, the Keys collection or the Values collection) have a ForEach extension method.

Is there any good reason why the ForEach() extension method has not been implemented on these collections, or is it just something that MS felt was not important?

Is it that unusual to iterate over Dictionary collections?  I often use Dictionaries rather than Lists when storing data pulled out of Databases, using the records Identity value as the Key.  I have to admit alot of the time I don't even lookup by the Id key, but it is just a habit I have gotten into...

Comment: why don't you just write an extension yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Eric Lippert explains why Microsoft didn't write a `ForEach` extension method](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

You can write one yourself:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action) {
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    foreach(T item in sequence) 
        action(item);
}

//Return false to stop the loop
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, bool> action) {
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach(T item in sequence) 
        if (!action(item))
            return;
}
```

Comment: Eric's article makes some good points. I hope people read that before they go too crazy using your answer.

Comment: Eric makes a good argument against a general `ForEach` on `IEnumerable<>`, but for `Dictionary<>` it would still be advantageous, because the plain `foreach` loop gives you a `KeyValuePair`, but a lambda could have two arguments, one for the key and one for the value, which would make the code look cleaner.

Comment: The link is oudated. Heres the new link: https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ He basically says that you should just use the original for each loop because it is more basic.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, let's upgrade my comment to an answer, so I can include readable code.

Eric makes a good argument against a general `ForEach` on `IEnumerable<>`, but for `Dictionary<>` it would still be advantageous, because the plain `foreach` loop gives you a `KeyValuePair`, but a lambda could have two arguments, one for the key and one for the value, which would make the code look cleaner.

```
public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, Action<TKey, TValue> action) {
    if (dict == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dict");
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item in dict) {
        action(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason (IMO) for there not to have been a ForEach extension method implemented on IEnumerable<T> (instead it is only on List<T>). I have created a ForEach extension method in my common libraries, it's only a few lines of code.

```
public static void ForEach<T>( this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action ) {
    foreach( var o in list ) {
        action( o );
    }
}
```