# conditional for each linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `List<string>` myList like shown below:

```
widget1
widget2
widget3
widget4
```

I'd like to show this on my web page like the following

```
widget1 | widget3 | widget4
```

**Let's just say if the string is "widget2" leave it out.**

is there a way to do this with a linq statement?

```
<div>
    <% myList.ForEach(x => Response.Write(Html.ActionLink(x.Name,"ActionMethod"))); %>
</div>
```

i know i'm asking too much but i thought i'd try.

Comment: what is your criteria to exclude widget2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331931/net-foreach-extension-methods-and-dictionary/1331950#1331950

Comment: @Paul `List<T>` already has a `.ForEach()` -- the OP used it above ...

Comment: Updated OP for Widget2 criteria.

Comment: @ckittel: good point. :) Though once the filtering is applied it will no longer be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<%= String.Join(" | ", myList
    .Where(x => x.Name != "Widget 2")
    .Select(x => Html.ActionLink(x,"ActionMethod").ToString()) %>
```

Then just modify the where statement to fit your needs. I guess it is a matter of preference, but I dislike to use Response.Write in views, and I try to avoid the ForEach() method because it doesn't work on plain IEnumerables.

Comment: i had to use ToArray() insetead of the ToString() because the String.Join 2nd parm looking for array, right?

Comment: You may have to - the overload to String.Join() that accepts an IEnumerable<string> was introduced in .NET 4. If you are using an earlier version of the framework, then you have to use .ToArray()

Answer (score 1):

You could use the String.Join method in combination with Linq:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
// populate list here.

string result = String.Join(" | ", list.Where(c => c.Name != "widget2").ToList());
```

[String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

Comment: Use a predicate on this list using linq, and use string.join with the result of the filtered list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };
var agg = list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (sb, item) => sb.AppendFormat((item == list.First()) ? "{0} " : "| {0}", item));
```

or if you don't want to do the first check every time

```
var agg = list.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (sb, item) => sb.AppendFormat("{0} | ", item));
if (agg.Length > 0)
    agg.Remove(agg.Length - 2, 2);
```

Comment: will this leave a trailing pipe symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<div>
    <% myList.Where(x => x.Name != "widget2").ToList().ForEach(x => Response.Write(Html.ActionLink(x.Name,"ActionMethod"))); %>
</div>
```

Introducing the "conditional" part before the `ForEach(...)` call.

Comment: is there a way to include the pipe symbol as a delimiter?

Comment: @rod I didn't realize that " | "ing  was part of the question as well, I assumed your `ForEach(...)` code was pseudo-code and was doing the piping.  I suggest looking to @AHM's answer (+1ed) for the complete package.